# How to open and then close an external window with tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have a GUI that needs to be initialized by opening a program called paraview and then closing it straight after.

I have created a button to run the code 'initialise' which is supposed to open the program and then close it. These commands work in the command line, the problem is that as long as paraview is open the code doesn't execute the kill command.

```
def Initialise():

call(("chdir C:\\Program Files\\Test\\bin && paraview --state=paraview-initialise-box.pvsm"),shell=True)
call(("tasklist && taskkill /F /IM \"paraview.exe\" /T"),shell=True)
```

Is there something i can do to remove the link between the gui and paraview so that i can run the kill command

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to terminate external program or window using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035271/how-to-terminate-external-program-or-window-using-python)

Comment: Unfortunately not, while the program is open no other functions are run until i manually close it